# Link to different parts/tabs of a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have a look at http://keithloutit.com/#news

I have a similar site, with all the content on the same page.

I would like to know how to fetch the correct part of the url. In this case it would be "news". I suppose its some regexp used on `document.location.href`? Hope you get the idea, otherwise ill try to elaborate. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript on the page has to get the hash from the URL:

```
window.location.hash
```

and then activate the currect tab.

---

**Note:** if you're merely linking to a part of your page that is not part of a tabular system, you don't need javascript. The page will automatically scroll down to the element with that ID.

Comment: How do you listen for changes to the hash value? (ie browser forward/backwards commands)

Comment: Modern browsers have a [`onhashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) event. If you have to support older browsers, [you should use a plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/).

Comment: Ok, cool.  And when you say "element with that ID" do you mean "`a` tag with that name"?  Or do browsers support it by ID now?

Comment: I suppose i need to bind the hashchange event in order to get the current and not the previous value, right?

Comment: @Tim - Any element with an ID would do.

Comment: @Johan - Correct. If someone comes to your page directly through that URL, you don't need the hash change event; you could just read it from `window.location.hash`. But, if you want to provide the same functionality for when they click the browser's back button - you have to listen to the hash change event.